# Can itext convert html to pdf?

Tags: html, itext

Can itext convert html to pdf.  Not an entire screen, but something like this:  A screen has a free form field where the user can enter something like this sentence enclosed in an HTML tags. This is a free form field that needs (bold tag here) important stuff bolded (end bold tag here) but nothing else bolded.  I will need to get this information from the screen exactly as it was entered and I need create a report that will include it, but have it look like this:  This is a free form field that needs **important stuff bolded** but nothing else bolded. Does itext have something that does this?

Answer (score 1):

In old versions of itext you can use htmlWorker, but this is now deprecated.
Now you should use the class XMLWorkerHelper and its parseXHtml method.

```
        try {
          Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
          PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
               (document, new FileOutputStream("c://test.pdf"));
          document.open();
          document.addTitle("test iText");

          XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

          String str = "<html><head></head><body>"+
            "<h1>This is a title</h1>" +
            "<p>This is a paragraph</p>" +
            "</body></html>";
          worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new StringReader(str));
          document.close();
          System.out.println("You should find you PDF in c:");
          }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did give it a try a while ago and I must say it isn't the best option for converting PDF to HTML. At first I thought my PDF was badly formatted due to the CSS, but even without CSS it looked bad. So personally for me, I would say iText does convert HTML to PDF, but it's stylesheet support is questionable. Again, I could be wrong, due to recent updates.